# How do you assign a Role when it's in userinfo and not the jwt claims in spring security Oauth2?

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, authorization, spring-security-oauth2, userinfo

How do you assign a Role when it's in userinfo and not the jwt claims in spring security Oauth2?

Answer (score 0):

One option that will work is to use a [Claims Caching Design](https://authguidance.com/2017/10/03/api-tokens-claims/) in the API, which will also ensure that User Info lookup does not need to be done on every API request.

See these resources of mine for how my (advanced) code sample works:

- [Java OAuth Integration](https://authguidance.com/2019/03/24/java-spring-boot-api-oauth-coding/)
- [Source Code](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.javaspringboot/tree/master/src/main/java/com/mycompany/sample/plumbing/oauth)

In the class above that I called 'SpringAuthentication', you would need to return the role from your user info in the getAuthorities method.